# What is the motivation of a Lie algebra's properties?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lie-algebras, symmetry

From what I know, Lie wanted to generalize properties of differentials, but (ab)' = a'b + ab', so why exactly did they construct an algebra that follows the jacobian identity and anti-skew symmetry? If they were working with one-parameter groups then why would generalizing cross products or jacobians help?

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58696/why-study-lie-algebras

Comment: Thanks. So if you use this analogue operation of a Lie derivative on a Lie group, the result is a kind of linear approximation of the Lie group that gives rise to a Lie algebra, and somehow the properties of that Lie algebra can be extended to the rest of the group if it is centered at the identity element? But then that leaves "how did they construct a Lie derivative to do this?"

Comment: Alright, thank you for explaining that.

Comment: Is there maybe an example you know of for this complete process? I see Lie algebras used in bits and pieces that are often more rushed in their explanation because they assume the reader has already had vast experienced with the topic. Is there a more encompassing example of identifying a Lie group, linearizes it with a Lie derivative, constructs a resulting algebra, then makes a deduction about the entire group using the algebra?

Comment: Maybe one example would be to deduce a global solution or invariant as a result of analyzing only local symmetries.